# Applications with graphics aren't shown in Windows 10 - shows transparent instead

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

I have a PC with Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and when I open programs with contains some king of graphics like:

- [Blender (2.76b)](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-76/)
- [Foldit](https://fold.it/)

The program mentioned here opens, but, the screen is transparent - it's like, the graphics of such programs aren't rendered - its screen is transparent.

First, I tried with "Foldit", I even create this [post with the issue there](https://fold.it/portal/node/2009268) with more details, but no answers has been added since.

Then, I downloaded Blender 2.90, I got an error about "a graphics card and driver with support for opengl 3.3 or higher is required" - searching in this [thread in spanish on answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/no-es-posible-instalar-opengl-33-windows-10/00d1ee33-5236-42df-b13c-873d14ddc4e2) it says that such graphic card is not supported and I cannot use the latest version of Blender; so, I downloaded a previous *(older)* version, but, Blender just appears, transparent.

I really don't know about system requirements, but, some threads ask for add the system details obtained by using "dxdiag.exe".

I add the main information got from "dxdiag.exe":

System Information:

> ```
>   Time of this report: 9/2/2020, 16:02:06
>          Machine name: <machine>
>            Machine Id: <guid>
>      Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
>              Language: Spanish (Regional Setting: Spanish)
>   System Manufacturer: MSI
>          System Model: MS-7309
>                  BIOS: Default System BIOS (type: BIOS)
>             Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 425 Processor (3 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
>                Memory: 4096MB RAM
>   Available OS Memory: 3840MB RAM
>             Page File: 5572MB used, 1343MB available
>           Windows Dir: C:\Windows
>       DirectX Version: DirectX 12
>   DX Setup Parameters: Not found
>      User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
>    System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
>       DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
>              Miracast: Not Available Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported  DirectX Database Version: Unknown
>        DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0387 64bit Unicode
> ```

---

Display Devices

> ```
>        Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce 430
>     Manufacturer: NVIDIA
>        Chip type: GeForce 6150SE nForce 430
>         DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
>      Device Type: Full Device (POST)
>       Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03D0&SUBSYS_CB8410DE&REV_A2
>    Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
>    Device Problem Code: No Problem  Driver Problem Code: Unknown
>   Display Memory: 2168 MB
> Dedicated Memory: 248 MB
>    Shared Memory: 1919 MB
>     Current Mode: 1360 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
>      HDR Support: Not Supported
> Display Topology: Internal  Display Color Space: DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709
>  Color Primaries: Red(0.646484,0.333984), Green(0.284180,0.601563), Blue(0.152344,0.076172), White
>  Point(0.312500,0.329102)   
> Display Luminance: Min Luminance =
> 0.500000, Max Luminance = 270.000000, MaxFullFrameLuminance = 270.000000
>     Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
>    Monitor Model: SyncMaster
>       Monitor Id: SAM0564
>      Native Mode: 1360 x 768(p) (60.015Hz)
>      Output Type: HD15 Monitor Capabilities: HDR Not Supported Display Pixel Format: DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_32BPP
> ```

I can add the generated dxdiag.txt file if needed.

Here is a sample with Blender 2.76b open:

[Sample with Blender 2.76b open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8OyN.png)

I really don't know about system requirements neithr what's wrong with this settings, since this compute I'm using I had Windows 7 professional 32 bits and [Blender 2.64](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/) and, with this same computer I'm using - no hardware modifications has been made - Blender was working,but, now, with this Windows 10 settings, the mentioned programs (*once opened*) shows as is shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8OyN.png).

Is that any information I can provide or any settings I'm missing?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess.  This is due to some security software running.  I have seen similar behavior in the past connected to security software blocking the successful execution of an application.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your comment. I don't have any security software apart of Windows Defender (*default in Windows 10*). If more info is need, I can edit the question.

Comment: @Ramhound by checking the NVidia control panel, I got that [this 3D sample logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vG3m.png) is shown, this is strange, IMHO.

Comment: Sadly, your GPU is vastly inferior to anything you need to run Blender, suspect it doesn't support the versions of OpenGL you think it does.  Unless you have the Nvidia drivers for that card installed on Windows 10 it's likely you only have basic display capabilities.  Your issues are likely directly connected to the card you are using and attempting to run Windows 10 without proper signed Nvidia drivers for the card.

Comment: That GPU is not supported at all in Win10. Last drivers were for Win7/8, in 2015. It's a 2004 GPU & was bottom-end at the time. Don't expect miracles. I'm pretty sure the entire 6k line was Open GL 2.1 only - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_6_series Open GL 3 came in 2008 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_3.0

Comment: @Tetsujin it would be possible create a partition where I install Windows 7 64 bits and then, there download the NVidia drivers and try if Blender will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my YouTube recommendations a video appeared with the title:

> [How to fix Blender OpenGL 3.3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySEhzgOxd7U)

In the linked video (*and similar others that mentions the problem with Blender and OpenGL 3.3*) the solution is download "opengl32.dll" [from the linked website](https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag) - by copy/pasting opengl32.dll in the destination (*in Blender case, in the Blender folder*), now Blender 2.76b is now running in my computer.

PS: I'm learning Blender and I totally understand that my computer wont just render complex objects as is shown in YouTube videos, but, my purpose is learn by doing very basic models/following tutorials, so, for my current goals/requirements, it's ok for me.